# How can I fix my Search bar and button, while also realigning my right menu?

Tags: css, html, alignment, navbar

I am trying to fix my nav bar. I tried to center my search bar while adding a button to it. It is just practice for html and css, but i cant figure out why my search button is so small, and also why my right menu is now aligned with my `<hr>`. It is supposed to be a simple youtube replica.....

```css
  
    *{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
     }
    body{
 font-family: Arial;
    }
    ul{
 text-decoration: none;
    }
    .menuOne {
 float: left;
 word-spacing: 12px;
    margin-top: 10px; 
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    }
    .menuTwo {
 float: right;
 word-spacing: 12px;
   margin-top: 10px; 
   margin-right:30px;
    }
    li{
 display: inline; 
    }
    .topNav .searchContainer{
 text-align: center;
    }
    .topNav input[type=text] {
    padding: 6px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    }
    .topNav .searchContainer button {
    padding: 6px 10px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    background: #ddd;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    hr.style-one {
    border: 0;
    height: 0px;
    background: #333;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ccc, #333, #ccc);
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
 <title>Youtube</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
 <!--This is the nav bar for youtube-->
 <nav class="topNav">
  <ul class="menuOne">
   <li>Menu</li>
   <li>YouTube</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="searchContainer">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
  <button type="submit" class="searchButton"></button>
  </div>
  <ul class="menuTwo">
   <li>Upload</li>
   <li>YouTubeApps</li>
   <li>Messages</li>
   <li>Notifications</li>
   <li>Profile</li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <br>
 <!--this is to seperate the nav from the containers bellow-->
 <hr>
 <!--Container for the video-->
 <div class="videoContainer">
  
 </div>
 <!--Container for the description of the video, to go below 
    video-->
 <div class="videoDescription">
  
 </div>
 <!--Side container for recommended videos-->
 <div class="sideBar">
  
 </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Explain with snippet or Image. For more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `absolute` to align center for search box. But the menutwo has too many `li`s, so I used smallr fonts that did not overlap.

```css
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 }
body{
font-family: Arial;
}
ul{
text-decoration: none;
}
.menuOne {
float:left;
word-spacing: 12px;
margin-top: 10px; 
margin-right:30px;
margin-left: 10px;
}

.menuTwo {
float:right;
word-spacing: 12px;
margin-top: 10px; 
margin-right:30px;
font-size:11px;
}
li{
display: inline;    
}

.topNav {overflow:hidden;position:relative;height:50px}

.topNav .searchContainer{
position:absolute;
width:240px;
top:8px;
left:50%;
margin-left:-100px;
text-align: center;
}
.topNav input[type=text] {
float:left;
width:138px;
padding: 6px 0;
font-size: 17px;
border: 1px solid gray;
}
.topNav .searchContainer button {
width:98px;
padding: 6px 0;
background: #ddd;
font-size: 17px;
border: 1px solid gray;
cursor: pointer;
}

hr.style-one {
border: 0;
height: 0px;
background: #333;
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ccc, #333, #ccc);
}
```

```html
<div style="min-width:1000px;margin:0 auto">
<nav class="topNav">
    <ul class="menuOne">
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li>YouTube</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="searchContainer">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
      <button type="submit" class="searchButton">Search</button>
    </div>
    <ul class="menuTwo">
        <li>Upload</li>
        <li>YouTubeApps</li>
        <li>Messages</li>
        <li>Notifications</li>
        <li>Profile</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<br>
<!--this is to seperate the nav from the containers bellow-->
<hr>
<!--Container for the video-->
<div class="videoContainer">

</div>
<!--Container for the description of the video, to go below 
video-->
<div class="videoDescription">

</div>
<!--Side container for recommended videos-->
<div class="sideBar">

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! just a couple of questions. 1. I tried to expand the searchcontainer, but the width is not expanding

Comment: @ChrisA Could you show me your code? (jsfiddle, codepen, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into [flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_flexbox.asp), as it will help you eventually tackle the problem of making your site responsive. [Here is another guide as well](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

What I did was change the topNav to `display: flex;` and just gave it a background colour. There is then a div that contains all of your content in your header, `.header-content`. This is set to be 80% of the width of the whole topNav, just to center all of your content more. It also has `justify content: space-between` which will put space between all of your elements.

Not sure as to why your button was so small as it worked fine for me. (You will need to view the below snippet in a full page to see your whole right hand menu).

```css
.topNav {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #D03237;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 50px;
}

.header-content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    font-family: Arial;
}

ul{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menuOne {
    float:left;
    word-spacing: 12px;
    margin-top: 10px; 
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.menuTwo {
    float:right;
    word-spacing: 12px;
    margin-top: 10px; 
    margin-right:30px;
    font-size:11px;
}
li{
    display: inline;    
}

.topNav .searchContainer{
    position:absolute;
    width:240px;
    top:8px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-100px;
    text-align: center;
}
.topNav input[type=text] {
    float:left;
    width:138px;
    padding: 6px 0;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
.topNav .searchContainer button {
    width:98px;
    padding: 6px 0;
    background: #ddd;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    cursor: pointer;
}

hr.style-one {
    border: 0;
    height: 0px;
    background: #333;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ccc, #333, #ccc);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Youtube</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    <!--This is the nav bar for youtube-->
    <nav class="topNav">
        <div class="header-content">
            <ul class="menuOne">
                <li>Menu</li>
                <li>YouTube</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="searchContainer">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
            <button type="submit" class="searchButton">Search</button>
            </div>
            <ul class="menuTwo">
                <li>Upload</li>
                <li>YouTubeApps</li>
                <li>Messages</li>
                <li>Notifications</li>
                <li>Profile</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--Container for the video-->
    <div class="videoContainer">

    </div>
    <!--Container for the description of the video, to go below 
    video-->
    <div class="videoDescription">

    </div>
    <!--Side container for recommended videos-->
    <div class="sideBar">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```